# How to store record information from a ListBox to a Table?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using the following code that is linked to a button `cmdAdd`. Using the 'On Click' event, the ListBox selection information is copied to a table `KitBuild`.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

  Dim strSQL        As String
  Dim db            As DAO.Database
  Dim rs            As DAO.Recordset
  Dim ctl           As Control
  Dim varItem       As Variant

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  Set db = CurrentDb()
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("KitBuild", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

  'make sure a selection has been made
  If Me.lstResults.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "At least 1 part must be selected."
    Exit Sub
  End If

  'add selected value(s) to table
  Set ctl = Me.lstResults
  For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
    rs.AddNew
    rs!ItemNo = ctl.ItemData(varItem)
    rs.Update
  Next varItem
    
ExitHandler:
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing
  Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
  Select Case Err
    Case Else
      MsgBox Err.Description
      DoCmd.Hourglass False
      Resume ExitHandler
  End Select

End Sub
```

Shown below is the table `KitBuild` where selections are saved. Currently, it only transfers over 1 piece of information from the selection which is `No` from `qryParts` into the column called **ItemNo** (ID #8). This works fine but I also need to transfer over the **Description** and **Unit Cost** of records from `qryParts` to `KitBuild`.

[image]

I tried changing the following to `rs!Description` and `rs!UnitCost` but the `No` value just shifts over to those columns (ID #9, 10) rather than providing the **Description** and **Cost**.

```
  'add selected value(s) to table
  Set ctl = Me.lstResults
  For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
    rs.AddNew
    rs!ItemNo = ctl.ItemData(varItem)
    rs.Update
  Next varItem
```

This is an example of the information I would like copied from `qryParts` to `KitBuild`.
[image]

How can I modify the code to include **No, Description and Cost**?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your ListBox has data in the order as on your last picture. Use this:

```vb
      'add selected value(s) to table
      Set ctl = Me.lstResults
      For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
        rs.AddNew
        rs!ItemNo = ctl.Column(0)
        rs!Description = ctl.Column(1)
        rs!UnitCost = ctl.Column(2)
        rs.Update
      Next varItem
```